# Can I create a view from a boolean selection of a numpy array?

Tags: numpy

If I create a numpy array, and another to serve as a selective index into it:

```
>>> x
array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13]])

>>> nz
array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

then direct use of `nz` returns a view of the original array:

```
>>> x[nz,:]
array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [11, 12, 13]])

>>> x[nz,:] += 2
>>> x
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [13, 14, 15]])
```

however, naturally, an assignment makes a copy:

```
>>> v = x[nz,:]
```

Any operation on v is on the copy, and has no effect on the original array.

Is there any way to create a named view, from `x[nz,:]`, simply to abbreviate code, or  which I can pass around, so operations on the named view will affect only the selected elements of `x`?

Comment: The last assignment uses `x.__getitem__(idx_tuple)`.  `x[nz,:]=value` uses `x.__setitem__(idx_tuple, value)`.  So while both use `[nz,:]` the underlying indexing operation is different.  The distinction between view and copy only applies to the `get` operation.  You could pass a `idx_tuple=(nz,slice(None))` around, but you still have to use the `x[idx_tuple]=...` syntax.

Comment: Thank you. I would have thought that qualifies as an answer.. but I'm new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy has `masked_array`, which might be what you are looking for:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray([[ 2,  3,  4],[ 5,  6,  7],[ 6,  7,  8],[11, 12, 13]])
nz = np.asarray([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

mx = np.ma.masked_array(x, ~nz.repeat(3)) # True means masked, so "~" is needed
mx += 2

# x changed as well because it is the base of mx 
print(x)
print(x is mx.base)
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I've been looking for There are some [warnings](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#operations-on-masked-arrays)..but my operations are nearly as simple as in the OP, not nested, shape-changing, or anything...  I'll test first before accepting. (There may be room for further commentary)